# While updating the variable with index, all the objects with the same key but different index also changing in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I tried to change the array of objects, actually, I created a task list that has user name, task description, and so on while updating the first index task, all the objects with different array indexes are also changing. I tried to recognize for long, but can't able to catch what's going actually,

Reducer.js

```
import actions from "./actions";
const stateInit={
    taskCount:0,
    taskDetails:[],
    templates:[],
    save:false,
    edit:false,
    createTask:[],
    userData: {
            task_msg: '',
            task_date: '',
            task_time: 36000,
            assigned_user: '',
            time_zone: new Date().getTimezoneOffset(),
            is_completed: 0,
        }

};
export default function tasks(state=stateInit, action){
    switch (action.type){
        case actions.ON_CREATE_TASK:{
            const {taskCount,save}=action.payload;
            console.log("create task", state.createTask)
            return {
                ...state,
                taskCount: taskCount,
                save:save,
                createTask: [...state.createTask,{userData:state.userData}],
            }
        }
        
        default:{
            return {
                ...state
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Create-task.js

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import store from "../redux/store";
import actions from "../redux/actions";
import '../styles/create-task.scss';
import {useSelector} from "react-redux";
import TaskTemplate from "./task-template";
import SaveTemplate from "./save-template";
const CreateTask=()=> {
    // const [templates, setTemplates]=useState([]);
    const onTaskCreate = () => {
        store.dispatch({type: actions.ON_CREATE_TASK, payload: {'taskCount':taskCount + 1,'save':false}})
        addTemplate();
        store.dispatch({type:actions.ON_ADD_TEMPLATES, payload:template});
    }
    const createTask = useSelector(({reducers}) => {
        const {taskCount, taskDetails,save,templates} = reducers;
        return {taskCount, taskDetails,save, templates};
    });
    const {taskCount, taskDetails,save,templates} = createTask;
    const {userData}=taskDetails;
    const globalTemplates=createTask.templates;
    let template = globalTemplates;
    const addTemplate = () => {
            template.push(<div key={`template${taskCount}`} id={`task${taskCount+1}`}><TaskTemplate/></div>);
        return template;
    }
    useEffect(()=>{
        // setTemplates(globalTemplates)
    },[])

    return (
        <div>
            <div className={"create-task"}>
                <div>TASKS <span className={"task-count"}> {taskCount} </span></div>
                <div className={"add-task-button"} onClick={onTaskCreate}>
                    <button>+</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            {templates && templates.map((template)=>template)}
            {/*{save?<SaveTemplate/>:templates.map((template)=> template)}*/}
        </div>
    )
}

export default CreateTask;
```

Task.js

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import store from "../redux/store";
import actions from "../redux/actions";
import DatePicker from 'react-date-picker';
import {useSelector} from "react-redux";
import TimePicker from 'react-bootstrap-time-picker';
import {wrapMapToPropsConstant} from "react-redux/lib/connect/wrapMapToProps";
const TaskTemplate=(props)=>{
    const [dateValue, dateChange] = useState(new Date());
    const [time, timeChange] = useState('10:00');
   
    const tasks = useSelector(({reducers}) => {
        const { taskDetails,edit, createTask} = reducers;
        return {taskDetails, edit, createTask};
    });
    const{edit,taskDetails,createTask}=tasks;
   
    const onFieldChange=(e)=>{
        let editingTaskId=e.target.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute("id");
        editingTaskId=editingTaskId.split("task")[1]-1;
        createTask.map((data,index)=>{
            if(index === editingTaskId){
                createTask[editingTaskId]["userData"][e.target.name]=e.target.value;
            }
        })
    }
    const dateChangeFormat = (val) =>{
        var splitDate=val.toLocaleString('hu-HU').substr(0,12);
        splitDate=splitDate.replaceAll(" ","").replaceAll(".","-");
        return splitDate;
    }
    
    return(
        <>
                <div>
                    <label>Task Description</label>
                    <input name={"task_msg"}  defaultValue={ props.task && props.task.task_msg && props.task.task_msg } onChange={(e)=>{onFieldChange(e)}}/>
                </div>
                <div>
                <label>Date</label>
                <DatePicker
                onChange={onDateChange}
                value={props.task?props.task.original_date:dateValue}
                format={"y-MM-dd"}
                name={"task_date"}
                clearIcon={""}
                />
                </div>
                <div>
                <label>Time</label>
                <TimePicker start="10:00" end="21:00"  step={30} onChange={onTimeChange} value={props.task?props.task.task_time:time} />
                </div>
                <div>
                <label>Assign User</label>
                <input name={"assigned_user"} defaultValue={ props.task && props.task.task_msg && props.task.assigned_user} onChange={(e)=>{onFieldChange(e)}}/>
                </div>
            <div>
                <button onClick={(e)=>onFormSave(e)}> Save </button>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default TaskTemplate;
```

Output with issue:
[image]

Comment: where do you get this `setTask` from ?

Comment: Sorry, Forget to remove that, Now I updated that code.

Comment: Looks like the way you are updating the value in the store is not correct . Any update to the store has to follow the process -> dispatch -> reducer -> store update .

Comment: can you add the code for `onFormSave` as well ?

Comment: I didn't dispatch, since the output from the process is wrong , that's my question too. I just console the createTask array, which I have to update in store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `state.userData` is the reference to the same object. And here:

```js
createTask: [...state.createTask,{userData:state.userData}]
```

you're just adding it again and again to the end of your `createTask` array. So any change to any of those objects (which are all the same object) is immediatelly reflected everywhere.
You have to shallow clone it at least. Something like:

```js
createTask: [...state.createTask,{userData: { ...state.userData } }]
```

Comment: Hey, this is the thing, what I really want. Thank you so much!!! :)